# What happens if minSdkVersion is below sourceCompatibility?

Tags: android, java-8, build.gradle, android-min-sdk

I upgraded `butterknife` to 10.1.0 which throws this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'butterknife-runtime.aar (com.jakewharton:butterknife-runtime:10.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19}
      > Execution failed for DexingTransform: /Users/<REMOVED>/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/65b6816001722128222b6880d16907c6/jars/classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

So I added to build.gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

However, the `minSdkVersion` is 19, but Java 8 requires API >= 26 if I am not mistaking.

Just for test, when I try to use an Java 8 feature like `stream` the compiler shows an error as expected:

```
Call requires API level 24 (current min is 19): java.util.Collection#stream
```

The projects compiles without error, but will butterknife just crash the app during runtime on a low Android version trying to use Java 8 language features?

Comment: What does that mean regarding my question?

Comment: So if I am not using Jack there won't be any issues?

Comment: Yes, that I understand, but what if a library uses stream, will Android detect that and throw a compile time error?

Comment: Derek, I am not using stream. But what if a lib uses it, will Lint detect that?

Comment: Still don't get it, `butterknife` uses Java 8 features (apparent by the error message), but when I enable Java 8 features through `sourceCompatibility`, there is no warning when `minSdkVersion` is 19? How can `butterknife` use Java 8 features but not require a `minSdkVersion` > 19?

Comment: It should be the same, what you wrote below is a constant of value 1.8.

Comment: Derek, I am not sure where you are you going with this; setting the compatibility in Android Studio > File > Project Structure to "Java 8" adds the entries in my post. While the enum value causes an `Unresolved` error in the dialog. How does this all answer my original question?

Comment: hi manuel, so can you find a way to solve the lint problems? i want to find the newapi lint errors while i added the sourceCompatibility with java8

Comment: @Colibrow I don't see this Lint warning anymore, unfortunately I don't recall what exactly helped. I am setting `compileSdkVersion 28` and everything works.

Answer (score -1):

> However, the minSdkVersion is 19, but Java 8 requires API >= 26 if I
>   am not mistaking.

Android Studio 3.0+ natively supports Java 8 and Jack was used to provide Java 8 support to earlier Android studio releases.

To start supporting Java 8 in your project, You should add following in your `build.gradle` (I assume you are already using Android Studio 3.0+).

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
```

***Note:*** According to [**Android Java 8 support documentation**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

> *If Android Studio detects that your project is using Jack,
>   Retrolambda, or DexGuard, the IDE uses Java 8 support provided by
>   those tools instead. However, consider migrating to the default
>   toolchain.*

Now, as you say you are using stream api, it would be supported on Android 24+ only.

The full support list for Java 8 features and apis as follows:

- **Lambda expressions**: Any. Note that Android does not support the
  serialization of lambda expressions.
- **Method references**: Any.
- **Type annotations**: Any. However, type annotation information is
  available at compile time, but not at runtime. Also, the platform
  supports TYPE in API level 24 and below, but not ElementType.TYPE_USE
  or ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER.
- **Default and static interface methods**: Any.
- **Repeating annotations**:   Any.
- **java.lang.annotation.Repeatable**:     API level 24 or higher.
- **AnnotatedElement.getAnnotationsByType(Class)**:    API level 24 or higher.
- **java.util.stream**:    API level 24 or higher.
- **java.lang.FunctionalInterface**:   API level 24 or higher.
- **java.lang.reflect.Method.isDefault()**:    API level 24 or higher.
- **java.util.function**:  API level 24 or higher.

> What happens if minSdkVersion is below sourceCompatibility?

If you deliberately use any one of the above APIs in min-sdk versions lower than they supported, (or in your case, minSdkVersion is below sourceCompatibility) it will give you [lint error](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks) "**NewApi**". It indicates something in your code isn't optimal or may crash. This answers your app crash on low Android version devices.